# Comparing two LinkedList<String> with ListIterator versus for loop and get(int index)

Tags: java, comparison, linked-list

I have two LinkedList objects that are always of the same size.  I want to compare them to see if they are identical in content.  What are the general performance and style implications of creating a ListIterator for each list and using a while hasNext loop versus using a counter (int i) and iterating from 0 to linkedlist.size() using linkedlist.get(i) to get and compare the values?  Is there a better way that I'm overlooking?

The only thing I can think of is that the ListIterator method may be better in that I could more easily swap in another Comparable list later (not that I plan on it).  I don't know what the two look like under the hood, so I'm not sure how I would compare them performance-wise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out `AbstractList.equals()` (which `LinkedList` uses) will do this automatically so use that. The code is:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == this)
    return true;
  if (!(o instanceof List))
    return false;

  ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
  ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
  while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
    E o1 = e1.next();
    Object o2 = e2.next();
    if (!(o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2)))
      return false;
  }
  return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

So don't reinvent the wheel.

One final note: don't use `get(index)` to iterate over a `LinkedList`. It's O(n) access (O(1) for an `ArrayList`) so a `LinkedList` traversal using `get(index)` will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Thank you.  That is similar to what I am using.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return false right away, when the two lists are of different size, instead of your last conditional return?

Comment: Yeah, I think a quick check on the sizes would be a good idea to prevent iterating through different sized lists in the first place.  Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

Random access into a `LinkedList` has horrible performance (it needs to start at one end and invoke `next` or similar repeatedly), so the `ListIterator` would be faster.

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense.

I also just realized I neglected the possibility of using list1.equals(list2), which, according to the API, should have the expected behavior (and I would assume they implemented it with Iterators).

Answer (score 1):

`get(n)` for linked lists is not a constant operation for classes that extend `AbstractSequentialList`; it's `O(n)`. From [AbstractSequentialList#get(int index)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#get%28int%29):

> This implementation first gets a list iterator pointing to the indexed element (with `listIterator(index)`). Then, it gets the element using `ListIterator.next` and returns it.

Generally you don't want to do random access on collections that don't implement the marker interface [`java.util.RandomAccess`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html).

> As a rule of thumb, a List implementation should implement this interface if, for typical instances of the class, this loop:
>
> ```
>  for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
>      list.get(i);
> ```
>
> runs faster than this loop:
>
> ```
>  for (Iterator i=list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
>      i.next();
> ```

As of Java SE 6, the implementing classes are `ArrayList, AttributeList, CopyOnWriteArrayList, RoleList, RoleUnresolvedList, Stack, Vector`.